# Ruby 2.4: How To Speed Up Regexp Initializing Dynamically For Use with .match?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.4

I just read about `Regexp.match?('string')` for Ruby 2.4 and was very excited to see the results!  But when I tried it out in my application, I hardly saw any gains.

```
str = 's'
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report(".match         ") { 100000.times { 'string'.match /s/ } }
  b.report(".match?        ") { 100000.times { 'string'.match? /s/ } }
  b.report(".match dynamic ") { 100000.times { 'string'.match /#{str}/ } }
  b.report(".match? dynamic") { 100000.times { 'string'.match? /#{str}/ } }
end
                 user     system      total        real
.match           0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.143658)
.match?          0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.029628)
.match dynamic   0.370000   0.010000   0.380000 (  0.371935)
.match? dynamic  0.260000   0.010000   0.270000 (  0.278614)
```

From the Benchmark, we see a tremendous gain from `.match` to `.match?`, but once i start dynamically creating complicated regex as my app requires, I'm loosing a lot of the gains.

My question is, why is there such a drastic difference and can I somehow create dynamic regexp to utilize the performance of `.matches?` in the example below? I tested my benchmarks using `ruby 2.4.2p198`

```
str = 'my text with words'
reg_str = '((^|[\s\"“])(cherry pie|cherry pies)($|[\s\"”\.\,\:\?\!])|(\#(cherrypie|cherrypies)($|\s|\#|\.|\,|\:|\?|\!)))'
puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times { str.match? /#{reg_str}/i }
}
9.380000   0.010000   9.390000 (  9.403821)

puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times { str.match? /((^|[\s\"“])(cherry pie|cherry pies)($|[\s\"”\.\,\:\?\!])|(\#(cherrypie|cherrypies)($|\s|\#|\.|\,|\:|\?|\!)))/i }
}  
0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.017900)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [/o](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options) modifier, so the interpolation is only performed once:

```
str = 's'
Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report(".match         ") { 100000.times { 'string'.match /s/ } }
  b.report(".match?        ") { 100000.times { 'string'.match? /s/ } }
  b.report(".match dynamic ") { 100000.times { 'string'.match /#{str}/o } }
  b.report(".match? dynamic") { 100000.times { 'string'.match? /#{str}/o } }
end
       user     system      total        real
.match           0.120000   0.010000   0.130000 (  0.117889)
.match?          0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.027255)
.match dynamic   0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.113300)
.match? dynamic  0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.034755)
```

Comment: FYI: in the real life nobody matches anything 100_000 times. That said, your advice is good for marketing department: tests will show the drastic performance increase, while in reality this change brings zero profit. In other words, **this answer is plain wrong.**

Comment: This looks promising to me. My use case is to scan for the same 10,000 regex like millions of times.  What's the trade off on using the /o/ modifier? Is it just taking up a lot of memory?

Comment: @mudasobwa i have matched a huge number of times in real life (not tinder). For example when processing logs, request headers, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You basically measure the string/regexp interpolation vs literal instantiation. The time of `match?` itself is not affecting the result of the measure at all.

To compare `match?` against `match`, one should instantiate the regexp upfront:

```
str = 'my text with words'
reg_str = '...'
reg = /#{reg_str}/i
puts Benchmark.measure {
  100000.times { str.match? reg }
}
```

The result of above will be roughly the same as in your second test.

That said, the string/regexp interpolation is the beast who takes most of the time. If you need a complicated interpolation in regular expression, the difference between `match?` and `match` won’t be noticeable, since the interpolation is a bottleneck, not the matching.

Comment: In my 2nd benchmark, hardcoding in a regex vs interpolating is causing like a 500x difference in performance.  I am still hoping there would is a way to generate regex from string that would be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

The speed improvement of `match?` comes from not allocating the MatchData objects and globals like `$1`. It just returns `true` or `false`. You can't use `match?` if you need to return something from the regex.

`match?` won't be any faster at compiling regex-strings into `Regexp` objects.

Perhaps in your code you can first create the regexes and then use those in the loop instead of constantly recreating them:

```
# bad:
lines.each { |line| puts "Found a match!" if line.match?(/abcd/) }

# good:
regex = /abcd/
lines.each { |line| puts "Found a match!" if line.match?(regex) }
```